# How to save RESPONSE CODE IN VARIABLE and use it in other sampler for assertion using JSR223 Listener

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I wanted to save the response code of one sampler in a variable and wanted to use the variable for response assertion in other sampler using JSR223 Listener
How can I do this?

I have defined variable vars.put("server",prev.getResponseCode()) and tried to use it in other sampler ,however I am getting response is null

Comment: Used Beanshell PostProcessor and was able to validate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463412/how-to-save-response-in-a-variable-in-jmeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your script, you need to amend your code as:

```
vars.put("server",prev.getResponseCode())
```

Once done you should be able to access the value as `vars.get('server')` in the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) or just `${server}` in other test elements.

Demo:

[image]

More information on `vars`, `prev` and other JMeter API shortcuts: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)

Comment: Thanks again for your help